# How can I remove the file location bar above code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: screenshot]

How do I get rid of the little bar above the code where it shows what file I'm in and where in that file I'm at? I just don't like the way it looks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are the breadcrumbs added in a recent version of VSCode. To disable them in the latest version, you can navigate to your settings (via the gear icon in the lower left), and under the User Settings tab, click Workbench, then Breadcrumbs, then uncheck the Enabled box.

Or if you are using the JSON settings editor:

```json
"breadcrumbs.enabled": false
```

I believe there may have been an intermediary version of VSCode where breadcrumbs were available but before the settings GUI was implemented, in which case the steps would be similar but you would have to navigate through the old settings page and modify the correct line of settings.json instead.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is this -

```
 "workbench.editor.showTabs": false
```

Add that to your settings.json, it should work immediately

Comment: It seems this question was about the breadcrumbs, not the tabs.