# Getting rid of some bar showing my project folder and name in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've got some bar up top that randomly appeared, probably after pressing a wrong shortcut. I would like to get rid of it as it is extremely annoying.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBEp0.png
It's the line that says `Metro RP > Gamemodes > metro.pwn`.
Its infringing my already limited work space. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the file location bar above code in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462408/how-can-i-remove-the-file-location-bar-above-code-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Indeed so. Thank you so much.